# Flatten XML structure by element with linq to xml

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, xml-parsing

I recently created a post about flattening an XML structure so every element and it's values were turned into attributes on the root element. Got some great answer and got it working. However, sad thing is that by flattening, the client meant to flatten the elements and not make them into attributes :-/

What I have is this:

```
<members>
    <member xmlns="mynamespace" id="1" status="1">
       <sensitiveData>
           <notes/>
           <url>someurl</url>
           <altUrl/>
           <date1>somedate</date1>
            <date2>someotherdate</date2>
            <description>some description</description>
            <tags/>
            <category>some category</category>
        </sensitiveData>
        <contacts>
            <contact contactId="1">
                <contactPerson>some contact person</contactPerson>
                <phone/>
                <mobile>mobile number</mobile>
                <email>some@email.com</email>
            </contact>
        </kontakter>
    </member>
</members>
```

And what I need is the following:

```
<members>
    <member xmlns="mynamespace" id="1" status="1">
        <sensitiveData/>
        <notes/>
        <url>someurl</url>
        <altUrl/>
        <date1>somedate</date1>
        <date2>someotherdate</date2>
        <description>some description</description>
        <tags/>
        <category>some category</category>
        <contacts/>
        <contact contactId="1"></contact>
        <contactPerson>some contact person</contactPerson>
        <phone/>
        <mobile>mobile number</mobile>
        <email>some@email.com</email>
    </member>
</members>
```

So basically all elements, but flattened as childnodes of . I do know that it's not pretty at all to begin parsing XML documents like this, but it's basically the only option left as the CMS we're importing data to requires this flat structure and the XML document comes from an external webservice.

I started to make a recursive method for this, but I've got an odd feeling that it could be made smoother (well, as smooth as possible at least) with some LINQ to XML (?) I'm not the best at linq to xml, so I hope there's someone out there who would be helpful to give a hint on how to solve this? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work - there may be neater approaches, admittedly:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
XNamespace ns = "mynamespace";
var member = doc.Root.Element(ns + "member");

// This will *sort* of flatten, but create copies...
var descendants = member.Descendants().ToList();

// So we need to strip child elements from everywhere...
// (but only elements, not text nodes). The ToList() call
// materializes the query, so we're not removing while we're iterating.
foreach (var nested in descendants.Elements().ToList())
{
    nested.Remove();
}
member.ReplaceNodes(descendants);
```

Comment: Hi Jon, that works indeed! Thank you so much :) The only thing I can't seem to figure out (bear with me, I'm not the sharpest knife when it comes to XML parsing) is how to preserve the attributes of elements. They seem to be removed when you make a copy of an element? :)

Comment: @bomortensen: They don't seem to have been removed in this case - I've still got contactId="1" for example... Ooh, I've just noticed it's removed the attributes from the `member` element itself. Will fix that, hang on.

Comment: @bomortensen: Yup, fixed it - last line is now ReplaceNodes, not ReplaceAll

Comment: it's interesting that `descendant` in `foreach (var descendant in descendants)` has never been used.

Comment: @Meysam: That was a bug - oops! Otherwise it won't do the right thing for deeply nested elements.

Comment: @Meysam: Okay, I now don't understand how it was working before. I need to look at it more closely soon...

Comment: @JonSkeet lol, due to your reputation, I thought it's a highly professional technique I am not aware of ;)

Comment: @JonSkeet I think the inner `foreach` loop is redundant because each `var child` is already in the `descendants` collection you are iterating through. So, maybe you could replace the inner `foreach` simply with `descendant.Remove()`

Comment: @Meysam: No, it wouldn't be - because we're after the *nested* elements within `descendants`. However, I can use the `Elements()` extension method - see my edit.

Comment: @JonSkeet Just tested the feature ;) +1 for nice answer by the way