# XElement.Root.Element keeps returning null

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am learning C# and trying to flatten XML following this code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9217686/flatten-xml-structure-by-element-with-linq-to-xml)

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
XNamespace ns = "mynamespace";
var member = doc.Root.Element(ns + "member");

// This will *sort* of flatten, but create copies...
var descendants = member.Descendants().ToList();

// So we need to strip child elements from everywhere...
// (but only elements, not text nodes). The ToList() call
// materializes the query, so we're not removing while we're iterating.
foreach (var nested in descendants.Elements().ToList())
{
    nested.Remove();
}
member.ReplaceNodes(descendants);
```

This is my XML (sorry I don't know how to post fancy code style)

```
<ApplicationExtraction>
    <IsCurrent>Yes</IsCurrent>
    <ApplicationDate>10/06/2015</ApplicationDate>
    <Status>Application Received</Status>
    <EquipmentType>Equipment</EquipmentType>
    <IsLoan>No</IsLoan>
</ApplicationExtraction>
```

There is namespace so I changed `var member = doc.Root.Element(ns + "member");` to `var member = doc.Root.Element("ApplicationExtraction");` but this returns NULL.

I also try `XElement sRoot = doc.Root.Element("ApplicationExtraction");` from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24650364/xdocument-root-element-and-other-permutations-return-null) I still get the same result.

I read up Microsoft XElement document but don't see how I can fix this.

What could I have done wrong?

Comment: "ApplicationExtraction" **is** the Root element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
XElement sRoot = doc.Root.Element("ApplicationExtraction");
```

will look for an element 'ApplicationExtraction' inside the Root.
If you want the Root, just reference

```
doc.Root
```

Comment: Thanks @Mr. White. This explains well and get me keep going with the rest of the code.

Answer (score 2):

In your XML, `doc.Root` is the root node i.e. `ApplicationExtraction` and there is no node `ApplicationExtraction` inside the root node thus you are getting null.

To fetch any specific node you need(for example):-

```
XElement member = doc.Root.Element("IsCurrent");
```

and to fetch the value inside the node:-

```
string member = (string)doc.Root.Element("IsCurrent");
```

Comment: Thanks @Rahul Singh. This helps me to have better understanding. Wow, just a little change can make the different. I thought doc.Root.Element("ApplicationExtraction") will access the node ApplicationExtraction  and so the Descendants().ToList() can do the job later.

Comment: @KD2015 - You're welcome. You can accept the answer if that helped you. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Ah, didn't know that. Thanks for the link